# Can I intentionally play cards that cannot damage obstacles?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

If I cannot do any damage to obstacles, can I intentionally play cards that are useless just to reduce my hand size to 3 to draw two cards? It seems like the game would stall badly otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can play cards that will not do damage. The turn order is set up so that you have played all cards you will be playing before you actually apply damage.

1. Play Cards
2. Apply Damage
3. Take Damage
4. Draw & Buy Cards
5. End Turn

From page 6 of the [rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/CAT27700_Crossfire_Full%20Rules.pdf?b979cc)

This section states you can play cards even if there is no obstacle to use their damage against

> You play cards from your hand during your turn, one at a time.
>   If your cards have any abilities other than damage on them,
>   resolve those abilities when you play the card. Your starting
>   decks don’t have any cards with non-damage abilities,
>   though. When you play a card, you don’t put it into your discard
>   yet. Instead, put it next to the obstacle that you want to
>   damage with the card (you can damage obstacles facing any
>   runner). You don’t place cards into your discard until after you
>   apply damage. You are allowed to play cards even if there is
>   no obstacle to use their damage against.

This section says you can partially damage an obstacle on your turn

> If an obstacle has a damage track level that requires
>   4 damage to clear, and you can apply only 3 damage
>   to it, the damage on that level will reset at the end of your
>   turn. The next runner will still need to deal 4 damage to it
>   to clear it during their turn.